# Nodejs cypher binary data and decypher in Actionscript

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, encryption, key

Is there any solution for this? I would like to implement pseudo-streaming video player with DRM protection.

So basically scheme like this:

- AS requests video at ?time=12, Nodejs encrypt it with a secret key and pass to Actionscript.
- Inside Actionscript, we decrypt it with the same key.

Flash player will be obfuscated, encrypted, key will be generated via some function instead of a raw unobfuscated string.

I haven't found a better solution for video stream protection. Do you have any solutions or ideas on how to do it?

Comment: This is fundamentally impossible.  The user can always read any key that you send to his machine.

Comment: It will be inside obfuscated & encrypted .swf It's more than enough for 99% people, who will try to steal our stream. I'm not looking for 100% defense. Just need an option to show digital rights owners that we are doing something to protect the content.